# Why does training using tf.GradientTape in tensorflow 2 have different behavior to training using fit API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am new to using tensorflow 2

I am familiar with using `keras` in tensorflow 1. And I usually use `fit` method API to train model. But recently in tensorflow 2, they introduced **eager execution**. So I implemented and compare a simple image classifier on CiFAR-10 dataset on both `fit` and `tf.GradientTape` and trained for 20 epochs each

After several runs, the results are as follow

- Model trained with `fit` API

  - Training dataset, loss is around 0.61-0.65 with accuracy of 76% - 80%
  - Validation dataset, loss is around 0.8 with accuracy of 72% - 75%
- Model trained with `tf.GradientTape`

  - Training dataset, loss is around 0.15-0.2 with accuracy of 91% - 94%
  - Validation dataset, loss is around 1.8-2 with accuracy of 64% - 67%

I am not sure why the model exhibits a different behavior. I think I might implement something wrong. I think it is weird that in `tf.GradientTape` the model start to overfit training dataset quicker

Here are some snippets

1. Using `fit` API

```py
model = SimpleClassifier(10)
model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()]
)
model.fit(X[:split_idx, :, :, :], y[:split_idx, :], batch_size=256, epochs=20, validation_data=(X[split_idx:, :, :, :], y[split_idx:, :]))
```

2. Using `tf.GradientTape`

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = model(tf.stop_gradient(train_X))
    loss = loss_fn(train_y, y_pred)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
```

The full code can be found [here in Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dBOSSzBWNLK8pi7LN2if299-1FiY1q8f)

References

- https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2
- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape?version=stable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things in `tf.GradientTape` code that might be fixed:
1) `trainable_variables` not `trainable_weights`. You want to apply gradients on all trainable variables, not only to the model weights

```
# gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

# and

# model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

2) Remove `tf.stop_gradient` from the input tensor.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
#    y_pred = model(tf.stop_gradient(train_X))
    y_pred = model(train_X, training=True)
```

Note that I also added the training parameter. It should also be included in the model definition, to include the layers that depend on the `phase` (like BatchNormalization and Dropout):

```
    def call(self, X, training=None):
        X = self.cnn_1(X)
        X = self.bn_1(X, training=training)
        X = self.cnn_2(X)
        X = self.max_pool_2d(X)
        X = self.dropout_1(X)

        X = self.cnn_3(X)
        X = self.bn_2(X, training=training)
        X = self.cnn_4(X)
        X = self.bn_3(X, training=training)
        X = self.cnn_5(X)
        X = self.max_pool_2d(X)
        X = self.dropout_2(X)

        X = self.flatten(X)
        X = self.dense_1(X)
        X = self.dropout_3(X, training=training)
        X = self.dense_2(X)
        return self.out(X)
```

With these few changes I managed to get slightly better scores, that are more comparable to `keras.fit` results:

```
[19/20] loss: 0.64020, acc: 0.76965, val_loss: 0.71291, val_acc: 0.75318: 100%|██████████| 137/137 [00:12<00:00, 11.25it/s]
[20/20] loss: 0.62999, acc: 0.77649, val_loss: 0.77925, val_acc: 0.73219: 100%|██████████| 137/137 [00:12<00:00, 11.30it/s]
```

The answer:
The difference was probably the fact that `Keras.fit` did most of these things under the hood.

Finally, just for clarity and reproducibility, the partial training/eval code I used:

```
for bIdx, (train_X, train_y) in enumerate(train_batch):
            if bIdx < epoch_max_iter:
                with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                    y_pred = model(train_X, training=True)
                    loss = loss_fn(train_y, y_pred)
                    total_loss += (np.sum(loss.numpy()) * train_X.shape[0])
                    total_num += train_X.shape[0]
                    # gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
                    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
                total_acc += (metrics(train_y, y_pred) * train_X.shape[0])

                running_loss = (total_loss/total_num)
                running_acc = (total_acc/total_num)
                # model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
                model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

                pbar.set_description("[{}/{}] loss: {:.5f}, acc: {:.5f}".format(e, epochs, running_loss, running_acc))
                pbar.refresh()
                pbar.update()
```

and the evaluation one:

```
# Eval loop
        # Calculate something wrong here
        val_total_loss = 0
        val_total_acc = 0
        total_val_num = 0
        for bIdx, (val_X, val_y) in enumerate(val_batch):
            if bIdx >= max_val_iterations:
                break
            y_pred = model(val_X, training=False)
```